# Can I use react-query to set cache and stale time based on response from query?

Tags: reactjs, caching, tanstackreact-query

Can I use react-query to set cache and stale time based on response from query?

Please see the following code.

```js
import {useQuery} from 'react-query' // v3.39.3

const {data} = useQuery('my-query', () => api.getSomething(), {
  cacheTime: data.cacheTime,
  staleTime: data.staleTime // <-- I dont think this will work though...
})
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do it, by using an instance from useQueryClient() with the setQueryData function inside the onSuccess call back function to update cash and stale time, like this:

```
import {useQuery} from 'react-query' // v3.39.3
const queryClient = useQueryClient();
const {data} = useQuery('my-query', () => api.getSomething(), {
  onSuccess: (res) => {
      //access to the new cash and stale time from the server response
      const {newCashTime,newStaleTime}=res.data
      queryClient.setQueryData("my-query", (prevRes) => {
        return {
          ...prevRes,
          cacheTime: newCacheTime,
          staleTime: newStaleTime,
        };
      });
    },
})
```

Comment: But `cacheTime` and `staleTime` are part of the query options, not the query result. Are you sure `setQueryData` is the correct method to use...?

Comment: you  can open the **ReactQueryDevtools** and try it !

Comment: This does not work. All it does is to add `cacheTime` and `staleTime` to the data.

Comment: Did you get this from ChatGPT?

Comment: no, I tried it on my project! it didn't work for you ?